# How can I increase the height of a control in WPF on increasing window's height?

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

Let's say there's a WPF window which has a `StackPanel` within which there is a control (`WebBrowser`, in my case). I want its height to increase when I increase the window's height. I am able to produce the effect in terms of width but no so in height.

xaml (which did not work):

```
<Window Height="700">
    <StackPanel Height="Auto">
        <WebBrowser x:Name="browser" Height="Auto" MinHeight="410" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: i don't want a dockpanel as it will restrict my overall functionality of the code.

Comment: "I am able to produce the effect in terms of width but no so in height" is simply because the default value of the StackPanel's [Orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.orientation.aspx) property is `Vertical`. StackPanel is not appropriate for what you're trying to achieve. Use a Grid or a DockPanel.

Comment: Stack panel squeezes its item(s) to the smallest possible size. Either vertically (if Orientation is Vertical) or horizontally (if Orientation is Horizontal).  Try to use Grid.  or in your case, nothing.  The WebBRowser can be the root element if it's the only one.

Comment: stackpanel is such a deception coz of its simplicity. had to change the entire structure coz of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `Grid` then instead of `StackPanel` (OR you can also have `StackPanel` within the `Grid` if really required), see the code snippet below:

**XAML:**

```
<Window Height="700">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="browser" Height="Auto" MinHeight="410" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```